# Is there a Tensorflow built-in function to create a matrix from a single-layered feedforward neural network without activation functions?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, I implemented a simple single-layer feedforward neural network with N inputs and N outputs without activation functions and biases. Simply, it is just a N-by-N matrix. **Question**: is there a Tensorflow built-in function that can express this neural network as a matrix easily? I know I can configure weights manually to construct a matrix; but, I am just wondering if a Tensorflow built-in function exists to do this configuration.

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.Dense` is equivalent to a single matrix multiplication if invoked with `use_bias=False` and `activation=None`, but what do you mean with "express this neural network as a matrix" ?

Comment: @noe Thanks for your answer. What I mean by 'express neural network as a matrix' is that I want a tensor array equivalent to the neural network so that I can do matrix operations, e.g., y = Ax, eig(A), etc., where A represents a matrix equivalent to the neural network, and x and y denote inputs and outputs, respectively.